# Overflow property does not work as expected in bootstrap card-columns, need suggestions

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm setting a transform scale effect on image in cards in bootstrap, under 'card-columns', but the effect is visible on scaling and then fits according to the card size. The 'overflow: hidden' has no effect on it.

I have tried applying 'display:inline-block'. Changing the parent card from 'card-columns' to 'card-deck' does the required behaviour. I would like to use the masonry effect of card-columns with the desired overflow effect.

```css
css
.card {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card .card-img {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.card:hover .card-img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
      <img class="card-img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/03/05/12/26/toque-macaque-4036088_1280.jpg" alt="Card image">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
      <img class="card-img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/06/04/21/53/airplane-4252410_1280.jpg" alt="Card image">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The required behaviour will be to have the transform scale effect without the visible image scaling and then fitting.

Answer (score 1):

While using overflow you have to have `height` & `Width` check below snippet.

```css
.card {
  overflow: hidden;
  width:500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.card .card-img {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.card:hover .card-img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
      <img class="card-img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/03/05/12/26/toque-macaque-4036088_1280.jpg" alt="Card image">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
      <img class="card-img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/06/04/21/53/airplane-4252410_1280.jpg" alt="Card image">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Sumit, I tried this with bootstrap 4 and it doesn't work. And setting the card's fixed height and width will stop the Masonry effect that 'card-columns' gives [card-columns in bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#card-columns)